What insects eat the inside of peanuts leaving the shells?
I put these peanuts in a mouse/rat trap and the insides of the peanuts were eaten leaving behind the shells. What insects can do these? Can ordinary ants do it?   What can I put that won't be eaten by insects, something not sweet enough to attract ants.

